# Angular Material mat-option component, where are the docs?

Tags: angular-material, mat-option

I can't seem to locate the api docs for **mat-option**. I have been to the api docs here:
https://material.angular.io/components/categories
but their doesn't seem to be any information on **mat-option**. I need to know what properties are available on **mat-option**.

Comment: I think there isn't any independent doc for mat-option, the most related is mat-select doc: https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview

Answer (score 3):

It is part of the Angular Material Core component documentation. https://material.angular.io/components/core/api#MatOption